# How to send Post Data to url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My Problem is that I have to integrate payment gateway. My request and response fine with Payment Gateway. But problem of this gateway is it only communicate with public server. Now I want to debug my later code which depend on response of payment Gateway.

Current scenario is,

A page --> payment Gateway --> B page

Now I know that response of payment gateway is fine so I want just send hardcoded response of payment gateway from A Page --> B Page by help of HttpWebResponse with POST Method,

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirectUrl);
request.Method = "POST";

string formContent = "data";    

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);            
dataStream.Close();
```

But it not send post data to my B Page so that I can debug my B Page

Comment: Have you tried `Flush`ing the stream?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirectUrl);
    request.Method = "POST";
    string formContent = "data";   
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(byteArray);            
    requestWriter.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
```